# ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only

Tags: database, sql, oracle, database-administration

I Am using oracle 11g and SQL developer tool. When i tried to retrieve rows from db i am getting error message as :-

```
ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only)
```

I looked for sgadef.dbf file and it was missing in home directory.. Can someone help me to make it working.

Comment: Why are you looking for that particular file, and why in your home directory? What does the alert log say is wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all check the status of the instance you work with (this may need to connect under administrator account):

```
select status from v$instance;
```

Probably you will get

```
STATUS
------------
MOUNTED
```

Under sys account try to complete

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

and check that it's completed successfuly.
If not - please share the result of output and alert log in your question.

Comment: I get the following error by running the command "ALTER DATABASE OPEN;", Error is  - "ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr_nab_less_than_odr], [1],
[22], [117], [119], [], [], [], [], [], [], []" in sqlplus. what can I do???

Answer (score 6):

just in case if someone comes to here for this question

RECOVER DATABASE;
and then 
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;

fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is related to a pluggable database then you can do the following:

1. Check the status of the PDB

> ```
> > SELECT name, open_mode FROM v$pdbs ORDER BY name;
>
> NAME      OPEN_MODE
> -------------------
> ORCLPDB   MOUNTED
> ```

2. Change the status to OPEN if it is not (like MOUNTED for example)

> `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE orclpdb OPEN READ WRITE;`

Comment: this throws out this error : `code`ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65054: Cannot open a pluggable database in the desired mode.`code`

Comment: @AmineHammou Have you checked the status of the PDB beforehand (step #1)? What is the status?

Answer (score 1):

SQL>

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN *

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01113: file 1 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\WIND\SYSTEM01.DBF'
```