# ORA-01219 Issue not happen with Oracle.DataAccess.Client but happen with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Tags: c#, oracle, database-administration

I'm trying to connect to database that is in mounted state and make a query of database status with this query “Select status from v$instance”, that is required to connect as sysdba, the connection string looks like this :

```
<add name="ORCL" connectionString="DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;user id=sys;password=oracle;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=SERVER1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(UR = A)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));"/>
```

And if you use Oracle.DataAccess.Client you can do this, but using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client with the same connection string result in an “ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only” error with the same connection string.

This is the code:

```
    public  class Repository
    {
       public static string GetServerVersion(DbConnection dbConn)
       {
        try
        {
            string result;
            using (dbConn)
            {
                if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    dbConn.Open();
                var dbStatus = GetStatus(dbConn);
                result = string.Format("Connected to Oracle Database {0}{1}Database Status {2}", dbConn.ServerVersion, Environment.NewLine, dbStatus);
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Format("Error : {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static string GetStatus(DbConnection con)
    {
        var command = con.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Select status from v$instance";
        return command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
```

ManagedDataAccess call Repository with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client connection

```
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

    namespace Oracle.DataAccessTest
    {
      public class ManagedDataAccess
       {
          public static string GetServerVersion(string constr)
          {      
            return Repository.GetServerVersion(new OracleConnection(constr));
           }
       }
    }
```

UnManagedDataAccess call Repository with Oracle.DataAccess.Client connection

```
     using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

     namespace Oracle.DataAccessTest
     {
        public class UnManagedDataAccess
        {
          public static string GetServerVersion(string constr)
          {
            return Repository.GetServerVersion(new OracleConnection(constr));
      }
    }
  }
```

And finally :

```
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        var cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ORCL"].ConnectionString;
        Console.WriteLine("Oracle.DataAccess.Client");
        Console.WriteLine(UnManagedDataAccess.GetServerVersion(cnn));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
        Console.WriteLine(ManagedDataAccess.GetServerVersion(cnn));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
    }
```

And this is the ouput:

```
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client
   Connected to Oracle Database 11.2.0.2.0
   Database Status MOUNTED

   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
   Error : ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 107:
   PL/SQL: ORA-01219: base de datos no abierta: sólo se permiten consultas    en tablas/vistas fijas
```

Any idea about resolving this issue?

Comment: So if you connect with sqlplus, what happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940636/ora-01219-database-not-open-queries-allowed-on-fixed-tables-views-only)

Comment: You can connect to the database that is mounted with any tool, sqlplus, sql developer, etc. if you do it with SYSDBA privileges, and also with connection of type Oracle.DataAccess.Client in c#, if you put DBA Privilege=SYSDBA; in connection string, but not with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client connection

Comment: Is no the same of ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only. The connection work with Oracle.DataAccess.Client, read it carefully