# Database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only Error

Tags: database, oracle

**My oracle database error due to electricity problem and pc shutdown during importing database **  My DB Version 10.2.0

```
ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only
```

I tried possible solution found on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940636/ora-01219-database-not-open-queries-allowed-on-fixed-tables-views-only) but no luck

Here what I try on SQLplus

```
SQL> shutdown immediate
ORA-01109: database not open
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.

SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  603979776 bytes
Fixed Size                  1250380 bytes
Variable Size             167775156 bytes
Database Buffers          427819008 bytes
Redo Buffers                7135232 bytes
Database mounted.

SQL> select open_mode from v$database;

OPEN_MODE
----------
MOUNTED

SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00322: log 3 of thread 1 is not current copy
ORA-00312: online log 3 thread 1:
'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\NRAT\REDO03.LOG'
```

Why this error and how can I solve this? Please help

Answer (score 2):

It seems your REDOLOG it's not synced so you either recover from a [backup](http://kpraveendba.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/ora-00322-log-3-of-thread-1-is-not.html), or maybe you have another REDOLOG file on group 3 and can overwrite 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\NRAT\REDO03.LOG' with that one.
Since you were importing data, maybe you don't mind losing the latest modifications. In that case go for [RESETOGS](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10gR2/backup.102/b14191/osrecov009.htm) option `alter database open resetlogs;`. 
Please read the links carefully since some of this actions will make you loose data.

Comment: I don't have another REDOLOG . Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Firefog too bad. It's always a good idea to have multiple REDOLOG files of the same group. If they can be on different disks, even better.

Comment: But i have REDO01.LOG  &  REDO02.LOG  is those usable?

Comment: @Firefog they are probably from another group. Look for redo log best practices on the web for more info

Comment: @Firefog How did it go?

Comment: I have created a new database and restore a backup which one day earlier and we put all the data manually to new one :(