# ORA-01219 - "database or pluggable database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables or views only"

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I've just installed oracle database 18c on my windows 10 machine. Then I used Oracle SQL Developer to login to the database that I've created during the installation with connection information below: 
[image: sqldeveloper1]
The connection was successful and when I tried to open the Tables, it showed an error OCA-01219:
[image]
 I've found this solution: 
[ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940636/ora-01219-database-not-open-queries-allowed-on-fixed-tables-views-only)
 that trying to make the database open. I have tried this but still no success, my database status: [image]

Can anyone please help to to solve this problem? Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem after having to restart the Oracle Service. The problem was the state of the pluggable database not that of the instance itself, which was "open" like in your case.

The following command worked for me (please replace "orclpdb" with your pluggable DB name):

```
alter pluggable database orclpdb open;
```

Answer (score 0):

If output of 'select status from v$instance' is open, can you please execute below query and let me know the out put:
    select name, open_mode from v$database;

Also, please let me know if you are trying to connect pluggable database. In case you are connecting to pluggable db, then run below query:
    alter session set container='';

Then after apply above approach. please let me know if any query further

Comment: Hi Channa, I tried the query you suggested and the output was: name = ORCL and open_mode = READ WRITE. And about your second question, how can I know if it is a pluggable database. Sorry for asking this, I just started to learn sql

Comment: did you create any table yet in this database? Also,sorry but from your error screenshot, I can only understand oracle error message. Not the complete message in the popup box

Comment: no, I have not created any tables in this database. just after the installation and I got this error

Comment: dear,Create a table first and then check if you are still getting the same error.

Comment: i have tried to create a table with sqlplus and open again in sql developer but the problem is still there

Comment: I didn't get 'i tried'? do u mean u created table or not? If it's created ,select the database and then connect to the table.

Comment: I did create a table, but when I opened the database, I still the same error message as I described in my question above